# Sharepoint product configuration fails in 3 tasks Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sharepoint

While doing sharepoint product configuration it fails with exception during 3 taks.

```
Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServer.StaticProvision(SPConfigurationDatabase configurationDatabase)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Join(Boolean skipRegisterAsDistributedCacheHost, Nullable`1 serverRole)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.CreateOrConnectConfigDb()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
```

**Error image**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the error, you could not connect to the configuration database. The log  gives you plenty of information ConfigurationDatabaseTask.CreateOrConnectConfigDb().

Check the communication between the sp server and sql server. Could you ping the sql server? Besides, make sure you turn off windows firewall.

Comment: Thank you helping me, Firewall is off, Database is in the same machine and i could connect the same in management studio, i could see sharepoint_config database gets created as well, so i assume  if it can create sharepoint_config  database then communication is established between sp and sql.

Comment: Check the account which you are using to connect to SQL Server instance, make sure it has the required permissions/roles to configuration database :Dbcreator;SysAdmin;SecurityAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late but I have had the same problem and I have just fixed this by accident lol. I read that it doesn't work if you set the password which has more than 16 characters due to how microsoft is. My original password had 18 characters and I changed it 16 and it worked. Also on your SQL Database you need to make sure that the permissions/roles to configuration database are :Dbcreator;SysAdmin;SecurityAdmin this can be done SSMS